# Patterns (preferably java) find floor space in sq ft

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following data that needs parsing.

The pattern could be (1) approx 1,000 sq ft (2)c. 500sqft (3) 2,100 sq ft

This is my code to find a digit but I need the above... in java

```
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d[\\d,\\.]+");
 Matcher finder = regex.matcher(price);
 if(finder.find()){
      try {
            String value = finder.group(0);
            // do something with value
            System.out.println("The floor area is circa " + value + "sq ft";
          } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // handle unparseable
            System.out.println(nfe.getMessage());
          }
      }
```

**Edit in response to Pshemo

I want to store the data in a database so I need a digit before sq ft or square foot or sqft or .sq.ft  so for example 2,100 sq ft  would give me 2100. (possibly from a long string such as a description)

Comment: Can you format your  question better since I don't know if `(1) approx 1,000 sq ft (2)c. 500sqft (3) 2,100 sq ft` is string you want to find, or is it list of examples of data you want to find like (1) `approx 1,000 sq ft` (2)`c. 500sqft` (3) `2,100 sq ft` or maybe you want just numbers like (1) approx `1,000` sq ft (2)c. `500`sqft (3) `2,100` sq ft

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward: You have an optional preamble ("approx", "c.", etc), a possibly-comma-delimited number, and then a suffix ("sqft", "sq ft", etc). Is there any particularly-problematic part here other than just writing the replacement code?

Comment: @jeff I guess I need a pattern to match the number and sq ft or square foot and then another pattern to obtain the number from a long description ** it might not be approx or circa or c. at beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<= )\\d(\\d*[,\\.]?\\d+)*(?=[ .]?sq)");
```

where:

- `(?<= )` - there is space before
- `\d` - starts with digit
- `(\d*[,\.]?\d+)*` - next is digit or digits, there could be comma or point with more digits - and it can repeats like in 100,000,000
- `(?=[ .]?sq)` - followed by space, point and "sq" or only "sq"

it will match with digits in (1) approx 1,000 sq ft (2)c. 500sqft (3) 2,100 sq ft (4) 3,3 square foot (5) 500 sqft (6) 23.sq (7) 34.678 sq or (8)  1,000,333sq but not: 6,,70 sq for example. But still you need to get rid of commas and points, but you can do it even with `String.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make minimal changes to your code:

- There are a variety of ways to select numbers from text, yours is decent. I'll wrap it in parentheses for later.

  ```
  (\\d[\\d,\\.]+)
  ```
- You specified a couple of square feet suffixes. They might look like this:

  ```
  [ ]*(sqft|sq ft)
  ```

Put those two together and you'll have the expression you're looking for. But how to select just the digits? Turns out that *every open-paren creates a capturing group, which may overlap and which you can extract with the `group` method you're already using*. Group 0 is always the entire matching expression, group 1 is the number, and group 2 is the suffix word (sq ft). Selecting `group(1)` rather than `group(0)` will get you the number you want.

---

p.s. Though it would be easy to specify the prefix, it's entirely optional and so I left it out. If you put it in, it might look like this:

```
(approx\\.?|circa|c\\.?)?[ ]*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost given up.  My solution is but I will amend the pattern is:

**amended to best possible pattern in order to store a digit

```
String url = "The floor area is 2,100 sq ft";
String url2 = "The floor area is 2,100 sqft";
String url3 = "The floor area is 20,000 square foot";
    Pattern.compile("\\d[\\d,\\.]+ (?=[ .]?sq)"); 
    Matcher finder = regex.matcher(url);
    if (finder.find()) {
        try {
            String value = finder.group(0);

            Pattern regex2 = Pattern.compile("\\d[\\d,\\.]+");
            Matcher finder2 = regex2.matcher(value);
            System.out.println(value);
            if (finder2.find()) {
                String value2 = finder2.group(0);
            // do something with value
            System.out.println("The floor area is circa " + value2 + " sq     
                                                       ft");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // handle unparseable
            System.out.println(nfe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```